# saving image clicked from camera or loaded from gallery in database and retrieving it

Tags: android, database, blob, store

I am trying to save the image in imageview alongwith the other fields that user inputs. I wish to store the image in database and it will be retrieved on other page when the data is to be viewed. What changes do i need to make in my "NewPat.java" as well as "PatientInfoDB.java". Here's my code..

```
public class NewPat extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
//Display pic

    ImageView iv;   
    Intent i;
    final static int cameraData=0;
    Bitmap bmp;
    //from gallery    
    Button buttonLoadImage;
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newpat);
        Initialize();
        setCurrentDate();
        addButtonListener();


        //Display pic
        InputStream is=getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

    }


private void Initialize() {

        //Display pic
        ib=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ibTakePic);
        iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivReturnedPic); 


         buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLoadPicture);

        ib.setOnClickListener(this);
     buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.bsave:

            //Collecting data from edittexts
            // getting Name
                 first = fname.getText().toString();
                 middle = mname.getText().toString();
                 last = lname.getText().toString();

                //getting the id of selected radio button 
                int genderId = radiogrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                genderButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(genderId);
                 gender = genderButton.getText().toString();

                //Getting DOB
                 date = dob.getText().toString();

                 //getting age
                 age= setage.getText().toString();

                 //getting admission date
                 admm =admitdate.getText().toString();

                 //getting address
                 addr = address.getText().toString();

                 //getting email
                 email=emailid.getText().toString();

                 //getting phone
                 phone = contact.getText().toString();

// How do i collect the image from imageview???? 


                //Inserting in PatientinfoDB
                PatientInfoDB entry = new PatientInfoDB(NewPat.this);
                entry.open();

// here i need to pass the image along with other parameters in database
    entry.createEntry(first,middle,last,gender,date,age,admm,addr,email,phone);
                entry.close();

            break;

            //camera case
        case R.id.ibTakePic:


            Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);//zero can be replaced with any action code
            break;


        case R.id.bLoadPicture:

             Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                     android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
          startActivityForResult(pickPhoto , 1);//one can be replaced with any action code              
             break;
        }

    }
```

Database code

```
    public class PatientInfoDB {

        public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
        public static final String KEY_FNAME = "pat_fname";
        public static final String KEY_MNAME = "pat_mname";
        public static final String KEY_LNAME="pat_lname";
        public static final String KEY_GENDER="pat_gender";
        public static final String KEY_DOB="pat_dob";
        public static final String KEY_AGE="pat_age";
        public static final String KEY_ADMISSION="pat_admission";
        public static final String KEY_ADDRESS="pat_address";
        public static final String KEY_CONTACT="pat_phone";
        public static final String KEY_EMAILID="pat_email";
        public static final String KEY_PHOTO = "pic_dp"; 


    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PatientdataDB";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "PersonalDetails";

@Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    KEY_FNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_MNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_LNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_GENDER + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_DOB + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_AGE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_ADMISSION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_EMAILID + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_CONTACT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_PHOTO + " BLOB);"
                    );  

        }

public long createEntry(String first, String middle, String last,String gender, String date, String age, String admm, String addr, String email, String phone, byte[] image) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(KEY_FNAME, first);
        cv.put(KEY_MNAME, middle);
        cv.put(KEY_LNAME, last);
        cv.put(KEY_GENDER, gender);
        cv.put(KEY_DOB, date);
        cv.put(KEY_AGE, age);
        cv.put(KEY_ADMISSION, admm);
        cv.put(KEY_ADDRESS, addr);
        cv.put(KEY_CONTACT, phone);
        cv.put(KEY_EMAILID, email);
        cv.put(KEY_PHOTO, image);

        //startobv
        //vc.put(KEY_DATETIME, value)

        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    }
```

OnActivityResult

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch(requestCode) {
        case 0:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                iv.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            }

        break; 
        case 1:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                iv.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            }
        break;
        }


    }
```

//Page where the pic has to b displayed i added this piece of code

```
PatientInfoDB entry = new PatientInfoDB(this);
            entry.open();
            Bitmap bm=entry.getPhoto();

        iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

// Added this method in my database i.e. "PatientInfoDB.java"

```
public Bitmap getPhoto(){
     Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT pic_dp FROM PersonalDetails ;", null);
                byte[] byteArray = c.getBlob(0);

                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    return bm;

}
```

But i got the error "android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundException:Index -1 requested,with a size of 2

Comment: Are you dealing with a single image at a time ?

Comment: yes.. One image per user

Comment: Then I think no need to store in DB, just store in any public static variable and access it from anywhere in the project :)

Comment: Can you give me an example? just so that i am clear? thanks. :)

Comment: ok , can you please upload the code of `onActivityResult()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this to get the bitmap from the imageview:

```
Bitmap myBitmap= ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

then you need to convert the bitmap to a byte array:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

then you can store it as a blob in the DB

EDIT:

to retrieve the bimap you get the byte array from the db and convert it back to a bitmap

```
    Cursor c = db.raw......
    byte[] byteArray = c.getBlob(0);

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

Now you can just set the `ImageView` bitmap to the retrieved bitmap.

Comment: Convert byte array into string and and save it in db as string.. and when are reading convert back to bitmap...

Comment: @john...How do i retrieve this image and display it?

Comment: or that, but then you could risk changing the underlying byte-array to adher to the default UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: the picture isnt getting displayed. i get an error "android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundException:Index -1 requested,with a size of 2"

Comment: you forgot to do `c.MoveToFirst()` i think that's why it gave you a `CursorIndexOutOfBoundException:Index ` when you tried to do `c.getBlob(0)`

Comment: Hey @john.. the imageview is displaying the same image for all users.. any idea why that is happening?

Comment: I couldn't really help you with that since I don't know what exactly you're doing or trying to do. Are you storing the blob according to the correct user and retrieving it via the correct user? Are you clearing the `ImageView` and refreshing it for a new user?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing and retrieving from DB, since your usage is for one time, you should store the image in a public static variable which you can access across whole project.

```
public static Uri publicSelectedImage; // Write this in NewPat at class level.
```

in your `onActivityResult()` assign value to this variable as following

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
publicSelectedImage = selectedImage;         // write this line.
```

Now from any other activity you can access this variable as following way,

```
Uri publicImage = NewPat.publicSelectedImage;
```

Comment: @TejalN, If you try this way, then it will save lots of code and time.

Comment: i tried it but it displays the picture only once.. if i go back and view it again.. it does not display the image.

Comment: @TejalN that's not possible.

Comment: see.. this application basically stores data of various patients alongwith their photos... this data can be viewed on another page where the photo is also displayed. So thats not happening